# How to insert a UTF-8 or UTF-16 character to a PHP string

Tags: php, barcode, utf

We have an existing system which reads a barcode and saves it in a database. When the saved barcode data is looked in the database it appears as `102\u001d211065\u001d9120` and when a var_dump is done it looks like "`101\x1D21881\x1D9120`.

I see that a group separator character is inserted into the string, which is \u001d and \x1D (https://codepoints.net/U+001D?lang=en)

I have the data of the barcode in a separate table in multiple columns. What I need to do is to write a query that finds a matching barcode. For this, I want to join the data columns, including the group separator character between them.

My question is, how do I create a string in PHP with the group separator character included between the concatenating strings?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was single quotes vs double quotes. When double quotes are used the UTF8, UTF16, etc. does get converted. So to include UTF characters the following needs to be used.

```
echo "This will \x1d work";
```

Initially I was trying to echo the string using single quotes which does not convert.

```
echo "This does not \x1d work";
```